# How do you customize the address bar icon in a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to add some custom branding stuff to our visualforce pages.  Is it possible to change the logo icon in the address bar on a Visualforce page?  If so, how?

Comment: standard page or visualforce?

Comment: they are visualforce pages

Comment: you mean the browser icon that is cloud ?

Comment: yes, we would like to change that to some image/logo that we choose

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The terminology for that image in the address bar is a *favicon*.

It's not mentioned in the question but if your Visualforce pages are exposed through a `Site`, you can upload your favicon into a `Static Resource` and then in the site configuration you can specify this resource to be used as the `Site Favorite Icon` and all pages which are displayed through the Site will use this as their favicon image.

Documentation:

- [Introduction to Force.com Sites](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites)
- [Creating and Editing Sites](http://na13.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sites_creating_and_editing_sites.htm)

Comment: Just a sidenote: I believe some IE versions do not apply this.

Comment: This works for Firefox, but I can't get it to work for Chrome :<

Answer (score 9):

Add this to the top of your Visualforce page, with the appropriate static resource link of course:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{!$Resource.Favicon}" />
```

Comment: Also please note to clear the browser cache as due to cache this appears to same as the cloud icon.Once the browser cache is cleared you may verify this !

Comment: I tried that + `<link rel="flavicon" type="image/x-icon" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.sampleFavicon)}" />` with `cache="false"` and I **can't** get it to work :<  (where the static resource is a `.ico` image)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me in Chrome. Not my answer but cross-posing from https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AhbMIAS

I also faced the same issue like favicon is getting displayed in Mozilla but not working in Chrome and IE.

when i made the following tags false it worked for me in Chrome too
applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag= "false"

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag= "false">
<link REL="icon" HREF="{!URLFOR($Resource.StaticResourceName)}" type="img/x-icon"/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following JavaScript hack will set the favicon on a Visualforce page that is NOT on a site in Salesforce Classic default:

```
<apex:page>
  <script>
  window.onload = function() { 
    document.querySelector('link[rel="shortcut icon"]').href = "{!URLFOR($Resource.favicon)}";
  }
  </script>
</apex:page>
```